# Installing a dictionary: file's extension .oxt

Tags: texmaker, dictionaries

I'm trying to install a dictionary in texmaker. All the sites I've found so far tell me that the dictionary is the same type one can find for LibreOffice, OOo, etc.

However, when I try to download that file, it comes with extension .oxt , and from what I could gather I need files with extension .dic and .aff . So, how do I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this a tex related question? I do not recognise any of the extensions you mention as being part of a tex system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm trying to install a dictionary in texmaker.

Comment: Oh OK I know nothing about texmaker:-) (thanks for the edit, I also changed the tags)

Comment: It's possible you need the dictionary for an older version of libre office. They were mirrored somewhere for TeX users last time I looked.

Comment: It is just a zip file with another extension, unzip it, and the dic and aff files are inside. If you unzip programme cannot handle anything that does not have the `.zip` extension, just rename the file

Comment: I've added it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxt files are just zip files with a different extension. Unzip it (rename if necessary) and you'll find the dic and aff files inside.

Bonus: if you are on a Mac or on Linux you can run

```
file file.oxt
```

And it will tell you what in earth this is. Very handy little tool.